# Is there an escrow-like mechanism that doesn't involve a trusted 3rd party?

Tags: trust, escrow

We know that escrow mechanisms are easy to implement when it involves a trusted 3rd party. For example if *A* and *B* don't trust each other they can simply send their goods to *C* whom they both trust. Then *C* can distribute the goods to them fairly.

However, is there a primitive that achieves the same when there isn't a trusted 3rd party? Basically, *A* and *B* don't trust each other and they want to exchange something. Can they do this without involving any trusted party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's "Decred cross-chain atomic swapping". It allows two people to exchange cryptocurrencies (currently BTC/LTC/Vertcoin/Decred) without trusting on a third party nor each other.

UPDATE: There's also Lightning Network atomic swap.

You can read about it on [Decred blog](https://blog.decred.org/2017/09/20/On-Chain-Atomic-Swaps/) or [Github](https://github.com/decred/atomicswap)